# Continuity of $ f(z) = \begin{cases} \bar{z}^3 & \textrm {if $z\neq$ 0}\\ z & \textrm {if $z=0$} \end{cases} $

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

If $$
f(z)
= \begin{cases} 
\bar{z}^3 & \textrm {if $z\neq$ 0}\\
z & \textrm {if $z=0$}
\end{cases}  $$ then
(a)$f$ is continuous only at $0$

(b)$f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$

(c)$f$ is discontinuous at $0$

(d)None of the above.

**Attempt:**
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\bar{z}^3=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 y\rightarrow 0}x^3-i3x^2y-3xy^2-iy^3=0 $$
and $\lim_{z\rightarrow \alpha}\bar{z}^3=\bar{\alpha^3}$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. Hence $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C},$ so option (b) correct. Is my explanation correct?

Comment: Yes, option b) is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is correct. But observe that $f$ is simply $f(z)=\bar{z}^3$ for all $z$.

Then we have

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow \alpha}f(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow \alpha}\bar{z}^3=\bar{\alpha}^3=f( \alpha)$$

for all $ \alpha.$